# Re: Youtube rating

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to work in youtube video rating. But i am stuck here. What is the difference betn these two youtube rating request?

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?id=gEqU0FMzPFo&rating=like&key=xxxx

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.rate?
        id=wtLJPvx7-ys&rating=like
```

I found one in guide and other on reference section of google developers. which one should i use to rate a video

the 1st one shows not found error although i signed in and the 2nd one i can authorize and execute in desktop browser (it works as well) but it's not working in mobile app where i used browser component to view youtube video. So i got confused which one should be used?

update:i used the 1st one as suggested but it gives 403 forbidden error

```
ConnectionRequest cr = new ConnectionRequest() {

    @Override
    protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
        JSONParser jSONParser = new JSONParser();
        results = jSONParser.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input));
        System.out.println("results " + results);
    }

    @Override
    protected void postResponse() {
        super.postResponse();
    }

};
cr.setPost(true);
cr.setUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?id=" + "kF94Jwx9ugU" + "&rating=like&access_token="+token+"&key=AIzaSyCAETrMkZeJ_nTq4ZdP1Jq6BFtA_11TR6I");  
cr.setDuplicateSupported(true);
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(cr);
```

Comment: Which one works? Just try both.

Comment: hello @DankVader i have updated the question. I tried both, still there is confusions which one to use. One give "not found 401" exception and other works in browser but not in mobile app where i use browser component. P.S i signed in before using this API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question :

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?id=gEqU0FMzPFo&rating=like&key=xxxx

This is the actual API hat you need to rate a video. While the other one,

> https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.rateid=wtLJPvx7-ys&rating=like

I'm sure this one is only an API-Explorer site so that you can try the API to see what the request looks like and also the response from the server.

note: when I tried it, it also fire to the former URL which is `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate`

Comment: thanks.. the 1st one shows not found although i signed in and 2nd one i can authorize and execute in desktop browser but its not working in mobile app where i used browser component to view youtube video. So i got confused which one should be used?

Comment: No prob. Well, I am sure you should use the first one.

Comment: hi.. i used the 1st one but it gives 403 forbidden error. I updated the code above. Am i doing anything wrong there? I have already got the access token after sign in, so it should not be auth error, i guess

Comment: hmm. is there any error message beside that? you might need to check this URL and see what is the actual error https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#videos_youtube.videos.rate

Comment: no other error msg.. just 403 one. I had already checked the error type in google developer but i cannot figure out since i get signed in and got the token as well so it cannot be auth error and i checked it in a no. of videos rating disabled by owner is not valid here as well

Comment: strange it should send you some kind of information on what is wrong. can you try to send the request using google oauth 2.0 playground and see whether it can send the request or not. https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: thankyou so much, it worked in google oauth 2.0 playground, so i checked the code where I forgot to set the scope in 0auth code.